# Styling ASP.NET Validator

Tags: css, asp.net, validation

I tried this code to style the validator and the input field:

```
.validError
{
    color: red;
}
.input_field
{
    border-color: red;
}
```

It didn't work. I also want to use jQuery like `slide` and `fadeIn` for the error message but I don't know how

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net Validator Default Style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247416/asp-net-validator-default-style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
.validator
{
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: What about the jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can find below link for more details. related to Styling ASP.NET Validator

[ASP.Net Validator Default Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247416/asp-net-validator-default-style)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the HTML it generates, which may differ on the version you have; with me, it generates:

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="false">First name is required</span>
```

So, the only thing I have to do is style the .field-validation-error class in ccs. as I normally do not have it as it's not generated in the File New Project template I just add it according to the specifications.

so in my site.css, I add

```
.field-validation-error
{
  color: red;
}
```

I usually also edit the input itself; assuming you also want to do that you could do something like this, adding a (!) error marker in the right side of the input:

```
.input-validation-error {
    border-color: #dc3545;
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + .75rem);
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 12 12' width='12' height='12' fill='none' stroke='%23dc3545'%3e%3ccircle cx='6' cy='6' r='4.5'/%3e%3cpath stroke-linejoin='round' d='M5.8 3.6h.4L6 6.5z'/%3e%3ccircle cx='6' cy='8.2' r='.6' fill='%23dc3545' stroke='none'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right calc(.375em + .1875rem) center;
    background-size: calc(.75em + .375rem) calc(.75em + .375rem);
}
```

And things start to become better,
You can go "creative" on CSS, you could use a global approach if your style guide allows it and state that

Every Input, when Focused (say selected by the user) and is invalid then:

```
input:focus:invalid {
  background: url("https://assets.digitalocean.com/labs/icons/exclamation-triangle-fill.svg") no-repeat 95% 50% lightsalmon;
  background-size: 25px;
}
```

this would be for each input that is detected by the browser and your css is loaded.